# Right click context menu command

Tags: windows, command-line, right-click

I have installed a program which added an entry in the context menu when right clicking a file.

I would like to simulate this right click on multiple files. 
Is there an option to determine the command line that is being executed with the file being right clicked as its argument?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, you have to do this with registery, found extension in registery and add your context menu item to it.

Comment: OK but where do I search it in the registry?